# Using JS how to dynamically change the text background color in a displayed html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a log file (`.log`) and wanted to open the log file as a HTML page. And for specific strings, I have to change the text color, e.g. if a text `apple` is there in the log file, then wanted to show this text `apple` in `green` color.

Any help?

Comment: Please let me know if it can be done without JS or there is other cool ways to do it as well?

Comment: Perhaps consider adding some code and your examples of what you are trying to achieve might better help users help you find a solution.

Comment: Can it be done? Yes. If it were myself in that situation, I would create a `<div>` that you can use Js/Jquery/AJAX to load the log file contents into. JS is also capable of searching strings for particular words, and then you can change it before creating the new string to display. Head over to w3schools and read up on JavaScript. Or if you post the code that you've tried, we can help you more specifically. `replace()` and `search()` are two useful JS commands that could help you with this. ;)

Comment: How are you converting the .log file to a html file? 

with css and the proper coding of your conversion you would not even need any javascript.

Comment: Got this requirement today & didn't get any specific solution at google search, so tried here. Have to code now, so was looking for simple & best way to do this. @Fata1Err0r thanks for your suggestion. Jeremy- If you can give me a reference link where i could get a sample?

Answer (score 0):

Having your program that converts the log file to html wrap all "apple" strings in the final html like this

```
<span class="myappleclass">apple</span>
```

and either using a css file or a style tag inside your head tag with a css class for green like this

```
<head>
<style>
    .myappleclass {
        color: green;
    }
</style>
</head>
```

would work.

Comment: Thanks.. But suppose i am not sure "apple" string will exists in the file or not & if it exists, then it can be a part of any line. So how to change the color then(if it exists)?

Comment: That's what I was mentioning with JavaScript. You can use it to easily search for those words, and then you can wrap it in HTML, as Jeremy suggests, to handle the coloring of it. With just HTML/CSS, you won't (to my knowledge) achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: So how are you reading the log file?

Can you walk me through the process?

Example of that:

1) I have the log file on my computer.
2) I run a program to convert into an html file
3) I publish the file

Or
1) user pastes the log file contents into a text box
2) I process it and show it on the webpage with apple being green

Or

something else.